# How do you get nth argument of a previous command at command line?

Tags: zsh

If you're at an interactive shell and you type something like:

```
echo this is it
```

Then later you can expand the first argument:

```
echo !^    #=> echo this
```

Or you can expand the last argument:

```
echo !$    #=> echo it
```

But now I'm wondering:

How would I access the *n*th argument?  I looked through [a related bash question](/q/1497811), but it seems like that only works when in a script, because `!n` just goes through my command history (instead of my argument history) - for example

```
    echo !1 #=> echo ls
```

which makes sense, because

```
    history | grep -E '^\s+1 ' #=> 1  ls
```

but what I want is `echo !(some correct index) #=> echo is`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This way:

```
~ $ echo this is it
~ $ echo !!:2
echo is
is
```

`!!:n` is the n'th arg
`!!:n-$` is args from n'th to last

Note: `!!` expands to the last command

---

As per OPs' EDIT ([moved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37282078/3744681)):

Second argument of the second to last command:

```
~ $ echo foo bar baz # This one is the target
foo bar baz
~ $ echo catz ratz batz
catz ratz batz
~ $ echo !-2:2
echo bar
bar
```

`!-n` expands to the command that was 'n' number of commands before the current command.

Note: `!-1` and `!!` are the same.

Comment: The `:` on these are often optional. E.g., `!!2` also gets the second argument of the last command.