# How can you access the second argument of the second to last command at the cli?

Tags: command-line-interface, zsh

For example:

```
~ echo foo bar baz 
foo bar baz
~ echo catz ratz batz
catz ratz batz
~ echo !!:2 #=> ratz
```

In this case the `!!:2` accesses the second argument of the last command. Is it possible to get the second argument of the second to last command which in this case would expand to `bar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As illustrated by @Jahid [in a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37278127/3744681):

Second argument of the second to last command:

```
~ $ echo foo bar baz # This one is the target
foo bar baz
~ $ echo catz ratz batz
catz ratz batz
~ $ echo !-2:2
echo bar
bar
```

`!-n` expands to the command that was 'n' number of commands before the current command.

Note: `!-1` and `!!` are the same